# How to use explicit GraphQL null input values in Mutations with Apollo-Client

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

How can I send explicit null values with apollo-client with mutations to apollo server?

I'm explicitly trying to set values to null like:

```
var model = { id: 1, integer: null, text: null }
```

with mutation

```
var query = gql`
  mutation ($id: Number!, $text: String, $integer: Int) {
    save(id: id, text: $text, integer: $integer) {
      id
      text
      integer
    }
  }
`;
```

Taking a look at the http request, the variables are not submitted to server. Only id is set.

I'm trying to use null values with Apollo-GraphQL

According to [apollo medium block](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/apollo-client-0-8-e8db5efc75fb) and [issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/852) explicit null values should be supported since 0.8.0.

Comment: what happens when you leave out `integer` in `model`? `var model = { id: 1 }`

Comment: same as setting them to null. In both cases the variable is not transmitted as part of the body variables.